# How to turn on Tap to Click on OS X Yosemite login screen

Tags: macos, trackpad

I have tried the recommendations under [Trackpad](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/blob/master/.osx) but have not been able to find out how to turn on tap to click at the login screen of OS X Yosemite.

Anyone been able to do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if this is possible only because the Tap-to click feature is a preference that is set by the user, meaning that if your Mac had two users, each user can have it on or off. This preference is loaded once you log in.

However, if your trackpad isn't physically clicking and you're trying to get around that, do this...

Once you startup and you reach the Login screen, on your keyboard, press the First letter of the User you wish to log in with. so if your name is "Steve" press the letter "S" on the keyboard and press "return" if you have a password it will prompt for it, else it will just log in to your user.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It used to work though. In OS X 10.8/9. https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/blob/master/.osx Scroll down to Trackpad, mouse, etc.